# Appium UiAutomator2 for testing a double screen application

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium, android-uiautomator

I am currently working on an Android application which works with two screens for the display.
On one screen, results are displayed and on the other screen, the settings are set by the user.

Additionally, only the second screen (the one with the settings) is a touch screen.

From the automated test perspective, I am working with Appium and UiAutomator2.

My problem is the following: Appium locates the elements only on the first screen. I can't locate the elements on the second one and I didn't find a solution to manage both screens.

I tried some operations with appium like switchToWebView() or switchToNative() but it didn't deliver the goods.

Would you have any suggestion?